# How to dynamically set the value of dataIndex for xtype gridcolumn in Extjs

Tags: javascript, extjs4.2

I want to dynamically set the value of a dataIndex for a gridcolumn based upon the availablity of data. My code is as follows:

Model:

```
    {
        name: 'idCcyAcc',
        mapping: 'order.idCcyCreditAcc'
    },
    {
        name: 'idCcyFullAcc',
        mapping: 'order.idCcyCreditFullAcc'
    },
```

View:

```
    {
                xtype: 'gridcolumn',
                filter: {
                    xtype: 'textfield'
                },
                filterable: true,
                dataIndex: 'idCcyCreditAcc', 
                text: 'Credit Account Currency',
                id: 'paymentPanelGridCrAccCcy',
                width: 150,
                renderer: Ext.bind(this.onRenderCell, this)
    },
```

how do i dynamically set the value of the dataIndex, based upon dataType, i.e.,

```
    if(type=Internal){
    dataIndex: 'idCcyCreditAcc'
    } else {
    dataIndex: 'idCcyCreditFullAcc'
    }
```

Any help is appreciated.

Comment: You can't set it dynamically, use a renderer.

Comment: If you need to set it only once on app startup then it's possible but if you need it at runtime then do what Evan advises.

Answer (score 0):

I did the following in the model which served the purpose:

```
    {
        name: 'idCcyAcc',
        convert: function(value, record){
            if(record.data.idProductType == 'Internal') {
                return record.data.idCcyCreditFullAcc;
            } else {
                return value;
            }
        },
        mapping: 'order.idCcyCreditAcc'
    },
```